# Expected number of swaps in bubble sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of swaps in Bubble Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331314/number-of-swaps-in-bubble-sort)

The problem is briefly stated below:
Given an array A of *N* integers, each element in the array can be increased by a fixed number *b* with some probability *p*[*i*], 0 <= *i* < *n*. I have to find the expected number of swaps that will take place to sort the array using [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

I've tried the following:

1) The probability for an element A[*i*] > A[*j*] for *i* < *j* can be calculated easily from the given probabilities.
2) Using the above the I have calculated the expected number of swaps as:

```
double ans = 0.0;
for ( int i = 0; i < N-1; i++ ){
    for ( int j = i+1; j < N; j++ ) {
        ans += get_prob(A[i], A[j]); // Computes the probability of A[i]>A[j] for i < j.
```

Basically I came to this idea because the expected number of swaps can be calculated by the number of inversions of the array. So by making use of given probability I am calculating whether a number A[*i*] will be swapped with a number A[*j*].

I have posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331314/number-of-swaps-in-bubble-sort) before but it did not had all the constraints.

I did not get any good hint whether I am even on the right track or not, so I listed all the constraints here. Please give me some hints if I am thinking of the problem in an incorrect way.

Comment: You can aswell perform the bubble sort and calculate the actual number of swaps ;) Anyway, you say that "Each element of array can be increased by a fixed number 'b' with some probability p[i].". When does that happen? on each swap? before sorting?

Comment: This happens before the array is sorted.And I think performing the bubble sort would make the program really slow as it increases the complexity, I would have to run it for every possible configuration of the array.

Comment: do you really think if this is a programming problem? This sounds like a problem to be done on paper. If you are writing a program and find this expected number, what is the practical use of this?

Comment: What is the initial array? The answer depends heavily upon what it is, or what the distribution is.

Comment: @TheRock, So tell me if I got this right. The initial array's elements are all the same, or sorted out. Then each of the elements can be increased by a fixed number with a certain probability. After that, a theoretical buble sort takes place, and you need to calculate the amount of swaps in this sort?

Comment: @PermanentGuest : Yes, I think that it is well modeled as a programming problem.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall : The initial array elements can be in any order, sorted or unsorted and you got the rest of the problem right.

Comment: Have you tried [CS Stack Exchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @tskuzzy : The initial numbers of the array is provided to me, the numbers can be sorted and unsorted initially, then the array elements can be modified as given above.

Answer (score 2):

The expected number of swaps for a given element is simply the expected number of elements to the left of it that are greater than it.

You can compute this quickly by the method of indicator variables and the fact that expected values have the [linearity property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

So suppose you are considering element `a_3`. Then the expected number of times it will be swapped is simply

> E[# swaps of a_3] = E[a_0 > a_3] + E[a_1 > a3] + E[a_2 > a_3]

Each of the individual expectations on the right hand side can be easily computed using basic probability.

Then the expected total number of swaps is simply the sum of the expected number of swaps for each element divided by two (since you double count).

Comment: I didn't get exactly why it is being divided by two. Can you please enlighten a little more about that?

Comment: If you have the minimal sequence [2, 1], you'd count two swaps without halving, since you would expect one swap for 2 and one for 1. But for each swap, there are two elements involved.

Comment: @Vatine : Why do i expect a swap for 2, because it doesn't have any element to it's left which is greater than it as said in the answer above, I would only count one swap for 1 as it is the only element which could have a value greater than it on it's left side.

Comment: To make things more clear below is a small example. Suppose the elements of the array are [10, 20] and the probability that each element can be increased by 15(the fixed number) is 0.5 for both. Then I can have 4 configurations of the array [10,15], [10,30], [25,15], [25,30]. So I expect only a single swap in case 3 which by calculation gives the expected number of swaps to be 0.25.