# Count number of bubble sort swaps in array without doing bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

hello i am trying to count the number of bubblesort swaps in array of size N but i would like to do it without doing the bubblesort , i have heard about merge sort and someone already told me that its some kind of merge sort modification ... i dont want to use this basic algorithm >

```
void bubbleSort(int * array, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++){
            if(array[j+1] < array[j]){
                int tmp = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = tmp;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

does anyone of you guys have an idea?

Comment: Copy the contents of the array that you would like to count the number of swaps for into another array, and perform the bubble sort on that array.

Comment: Whatever you do, I really recommend you do not try to write multi-language source files. Stick to one of C or C++. Writing multi-language source files is hard work and any advantage that offers (if any) is minimal.

Comment: Since you are programming in C++, I suggest you use `std::swap`.  The C language doesn't have this feature.

Comment: In `n`element array, in the worst case it's `n*n/2`.

Comment: @Tomas: why you don't want to perform a bouble sort? To not destroy your data, or for performance reasons?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one!

Comment: @Olaf and pmg: Isn't C++ a superset of C?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel: Whoever told you does not know at least one of them. They have different features and different semantics for some constructs with the same syntax. I will not have this discussion again, as this pops up at least once a day. Just do some research on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of swaps in Bubble Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331314/number-of-swaps-in-bubble-sort)

Comment: @Olaf: Could you recommend any good sources?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel: Please read my comment carefully again! If in doubt read the C and C++ standards. They are not that complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you can use the following function to calculate the total number of swaps:

```
int calcSwaps(int *array, int size) {
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
            if (array[j] < array[i]) {
                ++cnt;
            }
        }
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

The main idea is that in this type of sorting every element `array[i]` will be swapped with all elements `array[j]`, `j > i`, `array[j] < array[i]`.

**EDIT**

I'll try to explain it more carefully to avoid misunderstanding. Solution is rather simple. Consider the bubble sort algorithm. Let's look at the initial unsorted array. If we have `array[i]` element, how many times will it be swapped? Okay, we swap elements `array[j]` and `array[j + 1]` if `array[j] > array[j + 1]`. Every two elements can be swapped at most one time according to the chosen sorting algorithm. Also if `array[i] > array[j], i < j` they will be swapped because we want to get a sorted array in the end. It's easy to see that in this case we just need to get every element `array[i]`, calculate the number of `array[j], array[j] < array[i], j > i` (it'll be the number of elements that will be swapped with `array[i]` in the process of sorting), and finally sum all these numbers for every `array[i]` to get the answer.

Comment: This will not give the number of swaps, but number of comparisons.
Array is after first iteration changes in bubble sort. But in your case it will not change.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarSrivastava This **will give** the number of swaps. We don't need to change initial array to find the answer. It's easy to see if you sort manually a little array with paper and pencil.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarSrivastava I edited my answer to make it more explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

Modify merge sort so that in addition to sorting its input, count the number of inversions that were in that array. Let's prove it by induction.

**Base Case:**
Easy - return 0 inversion if the array size is less than or equal to 1

**General Case:**
Let's analyze the problem step by step.

We have two arrays to be merged. What kind of inversion could be there? An inversion(i, j) could be in the same half (left or right half), or i could be in the left half and j could be in the right half (i cannot be in the right half because we have the constraint i < j). However, by the inductive hypothesis, the number of inversions within the left and right half of the array would be returned by the respective recursive calls to each half of the array, so we only need to count the number of inversions across the two halves (i in left and j in right).

How do we count the number of inversions across left and right array? In the merge step of the merge sort, we are given a two sorted array (left and right). For each element left[i] in the left array we want to know how many element right[j] in the right array is strictly smaller than  left[i]
.Note that when we insert left[i] into the merged array, we know that every element to the left of j is less than left[i] (since they are inserted to merged array before left[i] ). So, each time left[i] is inserted into the merged array increment the counter by j.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int MS(int a[],int temp[],int left,int right);
long long int Merge(int a[],int temp[],int left,int mid,int right);

long long int MS(int a[],int temp[],int left,int right)
{
    long long int cnt=0;
    int mid;
    if(right>left)
    {
        mid=(right+left)/2;
        cnt=MS(a,temp,left,mid);
        cnt+=MS(a,temp,mid+1,right);
        cnt+=Merge(a,temp,left,mid+1,right);
    }
    return cnt;
}

long long int Merge(int a[],int temp[],int left,int mid,int right)
{
    int i,j,k;
    long long int cnt=0;
    i=left;
    j=mid;
    k=left;
    while(i<=mid-1 && j<=right)
    {
        if(a[i]<=a[j])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
            cnt+=(mid-i);
        }
    }
    while (i<=mid-1)
        temp[k++]=a[i++];
    while(j<=right)
        temp[k++]=a[j++];
    for(i=left;i<=right;i++)
        a[i]=temp[i];
    return cnt;
}

int main()
{
    int *a,*tmp,t,n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        a=new int [n];
        tmp=new int [n];
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[j]);
        printf("%lld\n",MS(a,tmp,0,n-1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A bottom up merge sort could be used for the same purpose, using the same Merge() function. The main difference would be cnt would be initialized = 0, then during the iterations (no recursion), the code would be cnt += Merge(... ) for each call to Merge().

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: [It seems to work](http://rextester.com/ZMGUN31656), but I'm not certain that my approach is correct!

Let's have an example array:

```
{3, 5, 1, 4, 2}
```

Find the smallest element's `index`. To move it to the beggining of the array, you need `index` swaps. In my example, `1` is the smallest element, `1`, with `index` `2`, is smallest element, so 2 swaps will be needed to place it on right place. After that, we have:

```
{1, 3, 5, 4, 2}
```

`1` is now in the correct place, so we can focus on the rest of the array to keep things simple:

```
{3, 5, 4, 2}
```

Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

unsigned swaps(std::vector<double>& data) {
    unsigned result = 0;
    while (!data.empty()) {
        auto smallest = std::min_element(data.begin(), data.end());
        result += smallest - data.begin();
        data.erase(smallest);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[See it working (hopefully correctly) online](http://rextester.com/ZMGUN31656)

Comment: Why do you use vector of `double`s instead of `int`s?

Comment: @Edgar: Because... well, my C++ teacher uses arrays of doubles. The type doesn't matter here, though.

Comment: Does your teacher use `double` to represent `int`? It's weird.  Also, type is always important, really.

Comment: We're working on numerical analysis recently, so we use arrays of doubles, but often use integers in example input anyway, for simplicity. I can't get your point that *type is always important*, how it's important here?

Comment: Okay, strictly saying to show your algorithm you can use doubles. But in this case, for example, you spend probably twice more memory that we really need storing ints like doubles. I'm sure, that the usage of C/C++ implies writing optimal code, so it's not true C/C++ way doing that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I'll have that in mind when writing new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow three simple steps. Make a copy of the input array, then increment a counter every time you swap and return that count.  Some thing like:

```
int bubbleSort(int * array, int size){
    std::vector<int> temp_array(array, array + size);
    int count{0};
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++){
            if(temp_array[j+1] < temp_array[j]){
                int tmp = temp_array[j + 1];
                temp_array[j + 1] = temp_array[j];
                temp_array[j] = tmp;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```